# Finding newlines in HTTP responses

Tags: c, http, sockets, http-headers

I currently have a program that basically reads html from a webpage. After sending the web server an http request, I get back a response where I use fdopen to read the socket:

```
FILE *webpage = fdopen(socket, "r");
```

then I have a loop that uses fgets to get each line and then print them to a file:

```
while(!feof(webpage)){
    fgets(newline, 1000, webpage);
    fprintf ...
}
```

This part of the program works fine, and I end up getting some test file like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 04:42:40 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.2.14^M
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M
Cache-Control: max-age=0^M
Expires: Fri, 18 Nov 2011 04:42:40 GMT^M
Vary: Accept-Encoding^M
Content-Length: 345235^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: text/html^M
X-Pad: avoid browser bug^M
^M
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

I want to find this newline that is right under xpad, and insert something right when this newline is found (basically do something right after the headers are printed. However, I'm not sure how to find the line, or what the ^Ms are for.

Currently I'm trying things like

```
if(newline == "\r\n"){
   ... 
}
```

or just "\n", and it doesn't work. I think its got something to do with the ^M but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: why not the ascii value of new line character 10 ?? instead of "\n"?

Comment: The expression `x == "\r\n"` will almost always be false in C, no matter what `x` is.  A standards-compliant compiler may even replace the entire expression with 0.  Look up how to compare strings in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^M (Ctrl+M) is the ascii carrige return, I believe you can search for just \r and not \r\n

I think ideally you want to do a regex check and check for a new line character at the beginning for the line ie ^\n alternativly you could just check the .length and see if it contains a new line if its 0. You just want to make sure you don't catch any false positves.

Answer (score 1):

For the headers, HTTP uses carriage-return + linefeed pairs to mark the line endings -- so the '^M' you see is the carriage return character.  Line endings in the body, after the headers, may be marked differently if the particular application allows it.

The end of the headers is marked by an empty line, so the first character on that line is that carriage return (not even other whitespace can appear before it).  So the first time you find '\r' as the first character on a line, you've found the end of the headers; all the remaining lines are part of the body.

`if(newline == "\r\n"){` doesn't work because you can't compare strings that way -- you're checking the address pointed to by `newline` for equality with the address of the string literal `"\r\n"`, which will be false even if the characters in `newline` match.  `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` would work, but since it's only two characters you may as well compare them individually (might even be faster).  It's also highly unlikely you'd get `'\r'` outside of a line ending, so you're probably safe just checking for for that.

If `buf` is large enough to hold any of the header lines, the following roughly outlines what to do (one approach, at least):

```
char buf[BUFSZ];
// ...
while( fgets( buf, BUFSZ, sock ) ) {
  if (buf[0] == '\r') {  // or (buf[0] == '\r' && buf[1] == '\n') to be strict
    // DO STUFF for end of header section
    break;
  } else {
    // DO STUFF for a header line
  }
}
// if needed, get rest of document
while( fgets( buf, BUFSZ, sock ) ) {
  // DO STUFF for a body line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those `^M` are the Windows newline characters. Or rather ASCII CR. Try searching for just `\r` instead of `\r\n`.